# around sign latex

Tags: latex, tex

I'm using Latex online (overleaf.com) for writing my trainee report. 
When I tried to introduce the sign around equal ≃ it doesn't work. 
I tried        `\simeq`   but not found. I entered at the beginning of the doc        `\usepackage{amsmath}` but it still error. I tried to introduce utf8 in this way      `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}`
but the command        `\simeq` is not working also I tried to put the sign ≃ by itself, and with        `\` it stills error too.
So my question is how to write the sign ≃ with Latex and which package should I use that allow Latex to read it correctly. 
Can you Help me?  Thanks for reading!

Comment: Maybe a search of LaTex Stack Exchange will help: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40769/how-to-use-simeq-in-equation

Answer (score 1):

You have to wrap this \simeq in '$' sign. Try using

> $\simeq$

.

Answer (score 0):

Amsmath should be sufficient, the sign you are looking for can be written as \simeq just as you said. Make sure your equation is put between `$$`, or `\ [ \ ]` (the latter will position it in the centre of the page).